# Python 3.6+ function to ask for a multiple-choice answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

```
# Standard multi choice question template
def multiChoiceQuestion(options: list):
    while True:
        print("\nEnter the number of your choice - ")
        for x in range(len(options)):
            print(str((x + 1)) + ". " + options[x])
        print("\n")
        try:
            answer = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Doesn't seem like a number! Try again!")
            continue
        if answer < 1 or answer > len(options):
            print("That option does not exist! Try again!")
            continue
        return answer
```

I created a template to ask a multi choice question in python. The loop will never reach it's end, since there is always a continue or a return statement. Is the `while True` condition appropriate for it?

Comment: "The loop will never reach it's end ...  Is the `while True` condition appropriate for it?" That depends on whether that is the intended behaviour. Is it?

Comment: Side note: `for x in len(options):` will produce an error as Python doesn't allow iteration over an integer. 200_success's approach is the way to go here, but for future reference, use `for x in range(len(options)):` if you really need to loop a certain number of times. This takes the `len(options)` integer and creates an interable out of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `while True` is fine, and is probably the best way to do it. However, the rest of the flow control is a bit clumsy.  By rearranging a few statements, you can eliminate the `continue`s.

PEP 8, the official Python style guide, recommends [`lowercase_with_underscores` for function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) unless you have a good reason to deviate.

The loop to print the numbered menu would be better written using `enumerate()`.  Also, Python supports double-ended comparisons for validating that the answer is in range.

```
def multi_choice_question(options: list):
    while True:
        print("\nEnter the number of your choice - ")
        for i, option in enumerate(options, 1):
            print(f'{i}. {option}')
        print("\n")
        try:
            answer = int(input())
            if 1 <= answer <= len(options):
                 return answer
            print("That option does not exist! Try again!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Doesn't seem like a number! Try again!")
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that `200_success` already covered most points. I would however like to add an alternative idea for the printing part:

```
print("Enter the number of your choice -",
    *(f'{i}. {opt}' for i, opt in enumerate(options, 1)),
    sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```

Explanation:
from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) we see that following signature for the print function:

```
 print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

we can therefore print everything with a single print call instead of three individual ones. I leave it up to you which one you perceive easier to use.